# schema qualified queries in ecto

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm trying to use ecto with postgres schemas, but the queries are directed to the public schema as table names when used from repo.whatever.

I can pass valid schema qualified queries as sql with query/3 like this:

```
 query(Repo, "SELECT * FROM schema.table", [])
```

And get the results from the table in the schema.

This:

```
 Repo.all(%Ecto.query{from: {"schema.table", model}})
```

Results in the expected sql which is:

```
 SELECT a0.foo FROM schema.table as a0
```

However, the query results in an error that the table schema.table cannot be found.  If postgrex sends "schema.table" to postgres, it should be interpreted as a schema qualified table name as in the direct query, right? Is postgrex parsing the table name somehow before sending it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Ecto.Query` struct has a special member called `prefix`. With PostgreSQL it allows you to choose a specific schema:

```
my_query = from(m in Model, where: m.foo == ^bar)
%{my_query | prefix: "schema"}
```

This will make the query (and all the produced models when reading) to use this schema.

You can also set prefix for a single model with:

```
model = %Model{}
Ecto.Model.put_meta(model, prefix: "schema")
```

This will make all the subsequent repo operations with this model (like preloading other models or updating this model) use the specified schema. As I said above - using the prefix for a read query (like `one/2`, `all/2`, etc.) will also set the prefix for the model.

I think the documentation for this feature is missing for some reason. I'm not sure exactly why, probably just an oversight.

Comment: added documentation to the project for this feature :-)